# Direct Linking (Amazon Mobile Associates API) not working for non-US items?

Tags: android, product, amazon-mobile-hub

We have implemented the Direct Linking feature (from Amazon Mobile Associates) and we intend to use it with non-US products (e.g. from Germany - Amazon.de). When accessing the generated german product's link, a "Page not found" is diplayed.

[image]

I noticed that the domain is american (www.amazon.com/..) and I read that the Amazon Mobile Associates API serves only U.S. users, **but is there a way in which non-US products can be displayed using Direct Linking?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this API is only available in the US. From their [main page](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/earn/mobile-associates) for this API:

> Amazon Mobile Associates Availability: The Amazon Mobile Associates
>   API serves **U.S. users** and works with mobile apps on Kindle Fire,
>   Kindle Fire HD, and Android phones and tablets.

Also, looking at the detailed [API Reference](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/earn/mobile-associates/javadocs/amazon-mobile-associates-javadoc), I could only find a `marketplace` parameter in the `User` object (and even without further digging, being part of the user object it probably won't do what you are looking for).

Comment: Thank you Hazzit. Afterwards I sent an email to Amazon and the answer was similar.